# Why does pg_dump add extra comments for public schema?

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, pg-dump

When I run `pg_dump -d <database_name> --schema-only --no-privileges --no-owner --no-comment --file db/structure.sql` it adds these lines to the dump:

```
--
-- Name: public; Type: SCHEMA; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

-- *not* creating schema, since initdb creates it
```

This is different for installations on different machines (not using Homebrew) with the same version. There it does not add these lines.

I installed Postgres via Homebrew.

Is there a way to configure this? Why are these lines added?

Tried different versions of postgres (15.5, 16.2). Tried on a different machine where it was not installed using Homebrew.

I could not find anything in the documentation for pg_dump: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/app-pgdump.html
I also could not find anything in the server settings: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/runtime-config.html

I expect the same versions on different machines to give the same output if the settings are the same.

Comment: Have you tried going the other way and seeing if the output is the same between these if you add `-v` or `-v -v`? Two things come to mind if you need equal output for the same dumped (set of) things: I don't think `pg_dump` uses any specific, repeatable order, so the rows it reads (if you also dump data) might come in different order each time, and the same might apply to schema/DDL - not sure it guarantees table `a` will be always dumped/listed ahead of `b`. `pg_restore` offers custom-order restore, but `pg_dump` doesn't seem to have dump order.

Comment: @Zegarek I don't think the question is about the order of generated statements but rather about *which* statements are generated (or not)

Comment: "*Why are these lines added?*" - https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump.c;h=10cbf02bebdd6f6232095d32c4c7c3f9037ea389;hb=HEAD#l10688

Comment: @Bergi Could be. My immediate impression was that it looks like an attempt to take a checksum or keep a diff aligned - additional data like those `--` comment lines would break both, and so would the reordering. Checksum would say they're unequal, diff would show differences, even though they contribute nothing to the actual schema. Making all these clients on all these machines either all output the comments, or stop them all from doing that would fix it, which is when I'd anticipate the reordering problem to appear.

Comment: This  is something you will need to bring up with the Homebrew packagers. Packaging is outside the Postgres core and differs as a result. What you are seeing came in at version 15(?) where there was a clean up of `PUBLIC` as a schema and a role. The comment is correct in that you don't see `CREATE SCHEMA public` in dump files now(15+). In my Ubuntu dump files there is no such comment, just an absent `CREATE SCHEMA public` .

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I created a issue for Homebrew: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/165726

Answer (score 0):

When I delete the whole data directory and recreated it by reinstalling I did not get the extra comments. The old data directory was a upgrade from a Postgres 14 data directory. Why this caused the extra comments is still unclear to me.